# Using find with -delete but not scanning a backup disk mounted in /media

Tags: find

I need to find all directories named ABC in /, but I want find to ignore (not scan) the path /media.

I've tried a few ways, as I found on the Internet, but none are working properly.

My latest three attempts were:

```
sudo find / -type d -name "ABC" -delete ! -prune -o '*/media/*'
sudo find / -type d -name "ABC" -delete ! -path "/media" 
sudo find / -type d -name "ABC" -delete | grep -v media
```

How can I do this, please?

Comment: `! -path "/media"` is for MAC not Linux

Comment: man `find`: "Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune  and -delete together."

Comment: An idea would be to use extglob `find /!(media|proc|sys) -type d` ... to exclude those directories

Comment: ... next, the order of your *actions* is important .... `! -path` must come before `-delete` or matched objects from `-name` will be deleted before they are denied by `! -path`.

Comment: So, I should try something like this:

    sudo find /!(media|proc|sys) -type d -name 'ABC' -delete

Do you think that will work?

Comment: yes, but you should check if extglob is on first `shopt | grep extglob` or `sudo find /!(media|proc|sys|dev) -maxdepth 0 -type d`

Comment: Remember, find -delete does not take any prisoners, ZAP, all gone, 2ns, you really need to be sure find does what it is supposed to.

Comment: Warning heeded Bac0n. I'm deleting files and folder for apps that I never use. Apps I installed and found out I don't want it, or I don't understand it, or I don't want to go back to university...